# form-data works using postman but not in react, post method, Springboot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot

We are using react js with springboot. We have written the service and check from postman form-data. It's working but when we use react js it's not working. Rest End point hit but not load the payload data to the service. 
for React we are using     const formData = new FormData() and append all the required input.
React Code

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("event", this.state.status);
formData.append("startDate", this.state.startDateTxt);
formData.append("sourceSystem", this.state.sourceSystem);
formData.append("endDate", this.state.endDateTxt);
formData.append("minPrice", this.state.minPrice);
formData.append("maxPrice", this.state.maxPrice);
httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/sa/searchData", true);
httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/form-data");
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = () => {
    console.log("httpRequest.readyState", 
    httpRequest.readyState);
    if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE 
      && httpRequest.status === 200) {
        console.log("httpRequest.responseText ", httpRequest.responseText);
        updateData(JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText));
    }
};
httpRequest.send(formData);
```

spring boot

```
@PostMapping(value = "/sa/searchData")
public List<DataResponse> searchData(SearchCriteria searchCriteria) {
    return saService.searchData(searchCriteria);
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain "does not work in react". Do you have errors ?

Comment: yes, getting error code 408.

Comment: Did you debug your request by using the Chrome Dev Tools ? You can have plenty of informations on your request. Does it point to the good url ? Do you use the  desired `Content-Type` ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the data in Request Payload on network tab.

Comment: So debug it ! Try to find the differences with your request on Postman.
Here is more informations about the HTTP Status Code 408: https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/408

Comment: also, When i submit the request, I am able to see the logs in controller but the data is not landed on controller.

Answer (score 0):

The error code **'408'** suggests that the problem is in the react code that is sending form data.

The server sends '408' error when the client has sent an incomplete request to it.

The problem can be traced to the block of statements beginning from

> 'httpRequest.open("POST", "localhost:8080/sa/searchData", true); ...

This code block is opening the connection with the server, but never finishing sending the request.

This is causing the server to time out waiting for the complete request from client, and eventually send 408 error.

**How to fix the problem?**

Add a .send() method after .open() to complete the sending of the HTTP request.

**An example of working code snippet:**

```
httpRequest.open('POST', "localhost:8080/sa/searchData", true)
// add headers and other parameters
// Send the request
httpRequest.send()
```

**More information:**

https://malcoded.com/posts/react-http-requests-axios/

Comment: CORS already applied. other services are working as expected. I am using source code for the testing. I have not build the code.

Comment: I am able to see the data in network tab(chrome) So data is posted but not reaching the service. It give us null values not what i posted.

Comment: When the POST is submitted, the browser will definitely send a request to the destination (Either full data or a dummy request, depending on the type of browser). The response will be shown only if the destination confirms that cross-origin request is allowed. That is why, the network console may show that some request was made, but the corresponding response was not obtained. Will it be possible to share the request and error from console and spring boot service?

Comment: Another workaround for CORS issue is to specify 'proxy' parameter in reactjs project for the development environment.  Example:  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080"  specified in package.json file will automatically redirect port 3000 (react port) to the server port (spring booot running on 8080).

Comment: I am getting 408. And on the same port, its not allowing me. When i run npm start, it suggest me to change the port because one app is already running on the same.

Comment: error is : "FilterPage.js:72 POST http://localhost:8080/sa/searchData 408
 {"apiVersion":"0.01","apiDomain":"gwrt-svcs","error":{"localDateTime":"2020-02-25T15:58:27.347","httpStatus":"REQUEST_TIMEOUT","errorMessage":"Exception Messagenull"}}"

Comment: Hi Naman,  the error code '408' suggests that the problem is in the react code that is sending form data.  The server sends '408' error when the client has sent an incomplete request to it. The problem can be traced to the block of statements beginning from  'httpRequest.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/sa/searchData", true); ...  This code block is opening the connection with the server, but never finishing sending the request. This is causing the server to time out waiting for the complete request from client, and eventually send 408 error.